# issue with query using sprintf() and format symbols

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make query using sprintf() and format symbols but it is not working

`sprintf('SELECT pk_i_id FROM %st_item WHERE s_contact_email IN %s ORDER BY dt_pub_date LIMIT 0, %d', DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $email, $countOfItems` )

here

```
DB_TABLE_PREFIX = "ww_";
$email = "email01@hotmail.com, email03@hotmail.com, email02@hotmail.com";
$countOfItems = 5;
```

Comment: it is table name. i.e. ww_t_item

Comment: dont you have specified your db earlier in your code ?

Comment: whats the error you have ?

Comment: if the problem comes from sql, try this : $email = "('email1', 'email2', 'email3')";

Comment: thanks singe batteur, my problem solved, I changed `email IN %s ORDER BY` to `email IN ("%s") ORDER BY`, is it ok?

Comment: well if your problem is solved, it's ok for me ;) check the answer if it's good 4 you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this format to search in multiple options :  $email = "('email1', 'email2', 'email3')";

Comment: Your answer is better, can you provide a good solution, I want something like that `$email = $arr;` where `$arr` is array;

Comment: dig this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php  -- create an array, then format a string with implode, and send it to your query...     ---- I will not do all the work ;)

Comment: Your reply helped me a lot, I have accepted and up voted your answer, please up vote my question if possible.

Comment: next time you have an issue like this, first try your query in a string (..."where x_y = $var1" ...) so that you know your problem comes from the query, and not from he use of sprintf() :)